# Can I book Xiamen Air award tickets using Delta SkyMiles?

Tags: loyalty-programs, delta-air-lines

I want to fly from Singapore (SIN) to Xiamen (XMN).  Xiamen Air has direct flights, and their website says it would cost 30000 miles from Southeast Asia: https://www.xiamenair.com/en-cn/egretclub/usepoints.html

I have sufficient SkyMiles on Delta, and Xiamen Air is a SkyMiles partner as well.  But when I search for award flights on Delta.com, the best option it has is to pay 45000 miles and connect in Guangzhou (CAN).  One of the itineraries it proposes even contains a CAN-XMN leg on a Xiamen Air flight (CZ 354 + MF 8302).  I've looked at both near and far dates--the entire grid of dates on Delta.com shows every available SIN-XMN itinerary costing the same and having one stop.

Is it possible to book flights on Xiamen Air using Delta SkyMiles?  The Air France Flying Blue website says the SIN-XMN flight may cost just 21000 miles, but it also says that Delta miles can't be combined with Flying Blue miles (of which I have none).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with Delta and they confirmed that it is impossible to book some flights as award flights, even though those flights are available with other SkyTeam award booking systems.  Apparently SIN-XMN is one of these flights. 
 Likely all Xiamen Air international flights are non-bookable using Delta SkyMiles, even though Xiamen domestic flights within China are bookable.